# Terms in neural networks: what is annealing temperature parameter in a softmax activation function?

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, softmax

I’m reading [this paper](https://www.groundai.com/project/self-supervised-audio-visual-co-segmentation/) about sound separation by using neural network method. It uses the term "annealing the temperature parameter in a softmax activation function". What does it mean?

Comment: Could you post the paper or give reference to what you are referring to?

Comment: @ChrisFarr https://www.groundai.com/project/self-supervised-audio-visual-co-segmentation/   Here you can access the paper the phrase I have problem in, is on page two before the first function.

Comment: Great, you may want to edit your original question with that information as well.

Comment: Also, this question belongs in https://stats.stackexchange.com/. I gave an answer, but in the future, know that stack overflow is for programming, not for the mathematics/statistics behind it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Annealing", in this sense, is an analogy to a chemical process in which temperature is reduced.
Here, too, the 'temperature' term in the softmax is reduced, changing it gradually from a 'soft' sigmoid function to a 'sharp' [argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) 
Try plotting a softmax function for yourself with different temperatures, you'll see the difference...